# lattice xyplot panel.abline - how to add different horizontal lines based on x values?

Tags: r, lattice

How can I draw horizontal lines in each graph based on specified x values? For example, when I have X=1 on x-axis, the matched dot on the plot is (1,y0), and then consequently draw a horizontal line Y=y0?

A working example using iris data with only a vertical line at x=0.5:

```
iris = read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data", sep=',', header=F)
names(iris) = c("sepal.length", "sepal.width", "petal.length", "petal.width", "iris.type")


xyplot(sepal.length ~ petal.width | iris.type, data = iris,
    panel = function(...) {
        panel.abline(v=0.5, lty = "dotted", col = "black")
        panel.xyplot(...)
})
```

But I'd also want to have horizontal lines shown in this way:
See in the `iris-setosa` graph(panel), a horizontal line is marked through the point at (0.5,y)--I draw this manually.   I don't know how to specify y in the panel.abline, since y is a variable that appears different for each panel.

In my actual data, my x and y have one-to-one relation.

I thought it should be a simple problem, but have no idea how to work this around. I hope this is clearer.

[image]

Comment: a working example would make it easier for us to help you. That aside, did you look at the help function for `?panel.abline`?

Comment: @EricFail I added an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: There is only one petal.width value that equals 0.5 and this identifies it and draws a horizontal line at the associated sepal.length value.

```
xyplot(sepal.length ~ petal.width | iris.type, data = iris,
    panel = function( x,y,...) {
        panel.abline( h=y[ which(x==0.5) ], lty = "dotted", col = "black")
        panel.xyplot( x,y,...)
})
```

I tested to make sure that it also handles multiple matches in multiple panels, which it does. If you wanted to test for multiple values it would be:

```
... (h=y[ which(x %in% values) ] , ...
```

And if I don't, then somebody will surely come along and point out that the `which` is not needed, since R supports logical indexing as well as numeric indexing.

Comment: Yes, I do ask for horizontal lines. But these horizontal lines should be assigned/decided based on what values on X-axis is (say, if X=1, there will be a point (1,y0) on the plot.Then I'm going to draw a horizontal line going through that point).  In panel.abline examples I see they all use codes like h=c(seq(0,1,0.2)), etc., which cannot serve my purpose because these are pre-specified. Which part is confusing?

Comment: What's still unclear is how many panels there are. It now appears that you want to reference the values of Y based on the values of X that match the vector, and I still cannot tell whether these decisions should be restricted to a particular panel. Are you saying you know there are X-values in every panel that can be selected  from all the target vector values, or are you saying you want to select those X-values, one for each panel. ?

Comment: Yes, reference is what I want. They should be applied to all the panels.  In my posted example, there can't be horizontal lines for the other two panels (because there are no points). But in my actual data, x and y are always 1-to-1 matched and each x must have its y.

Comment: This worked for me when plotting multiples groups of data as well. Very clever, thanks!